# Sequelize: One model many associations

Tags: sequelize.js, associations

I have a project with models User and Event where a user can have many events(one-to-many) and user can follow many events(many-to-many), i have the following associations:

```
User.hasMany(Event, {
  onDelete: "SET NULL",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
Event.belongsTo(User);

User.belongsToMany(Event, { through: "followedEvents" });
Event.belongsToMany(User, { through: "followedEvents" });
```

I want to use the built in method user.getEvents() to get the events a user follows from the joint many-to-many 'followedEvents' table. But when I do that it automatically gets the rows from the one-to-many table. Is there a way to specify which one i want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use aliases for all such associationsin order to distinguish them later:

```js
User.hasMany(Event, {
  onDelete: "SET NULL",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
  as: 'events'
});
Event.belongsTo(User, { as: 'user' });

User.belongsToMany(Event, { through: "followedEvents", as: 'follEvents' });
Event.belongsToMany(User, { through: "followedEvents". as: 'follUsers' });
```

That way you will have `user.getEvents()` and `user.getFollEvents()`